# Dynamically change the style of an undeclared html child component in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, primeng

I'm trying to dynamically change the style of an undeclared div. I'm using Angular and PrimeNG, and it's creating divs that I'm having trouble accessing through inline styles. The goal is to have a user input a width as a string (500px, 30rem, etc) and that width be text interpolated into those invisible divs.

Here is my HTML

```
<p-card>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="percent basin-color-info">
      <h2>{{ percentage }}%</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h4>Percentage of time when outstanding risks are received</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="break"><hr /></div>
    <div class="days">
      <h5>{{ days }}&nbsp;Days</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><h4>on average to correct outstanding risks</h4></div>
  </div>
</p-card>
```

If I use inspector, it shows the following layout:

```
<p-card> (This is in the HTML)
 <div class="p-card"> (This is **not** in the HTML)
  <div> (This is **not** in the HTML)
   <div> (This is **not** in the HTML)
    <div class="wrapper"> (This is in the HTML)
    ...
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</p-card>
```

I know that if I change the width of the first undeclared div with the p-card class in the inspector, the card changes how I'd like it to.

My hope is that I can use text interpolation {{ 500px }} or some sort of CSS injection to change the style of the undeclared divs, or some other workaround..

The p-card element from primeNG documentation says inline styles are an acceptable attribute but for some reason it doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Vincent Thomason,

From what I Understood, you are trying to style the div that is nested inside the p-card, that you don't have access to in your component HTML.

The only solution that I see is to give your p-card an id. Then use that id in querySelector and select the div inside ('myCardId>.p-card').

Here is a working stackblitz with what you want to accomplish:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nxjpwe?file=src/app/app.component.ts